# Get Details of retired jobs in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I need to get the following Details for  retired jobs in hadoop job tracker using Java.

- job id
- user
- Name (of job)
- status
- Start time
- finish Time.
- duration

Basically most of these above are displayed by the `jobtracker.jsp` URL.

And i need to capture them for auditing purposes.

Please let me know how to access the above fields.

Code examples would be very helpful

With the below mention code , I can only able to get Completed jobs details, sample code snippet:

```
JobClient client = new JobClient(getConf());    
for (JobStatus job : client.getAllJobs()) {    
    if (job.isJobComplete()) {    
        Stirng jobName = job.getJobName();    
        int jobStatus = job.getJobStatus();    
        // .. you get the idea    
    }    
}
```

Need help!!

Thanks ins advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check in

**In the Job History**

**Key:** hadoop.job.history.location

**Key (H21):** mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.location

**Default:** file:///${hadoop.log.dir}/history

**Retention:** up to a max. of 30 days  (see General Job File Notes below)

**Note:** The value for this key is treated as a URI, in other words you can store the job files in HDFS or on the local file system (which is the default).

For more info

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/

Comment: Answer is not helpful :-(